# Custom toast inflate root meaning

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-toast

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

This is a lines of creating custom toast (from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

It works fine, but I don't know why use the code

```
(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root)
```

I think `findViewById` method runs find view "present" element,
so that method returns null,

That means, meaningless code, doesn't it?

Why I wonder that problem is I try to use create custom toast in Service

Service has not findViewById, you know,

so I just try to inflate(id, null) that lead to my layout broken,

I already read http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/ article.

How can I inflate properly without my layout parameter loss information

Comment: did you import R from android.R?

Comment: not import R from android.R, you can see xml file in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"